# how to use .get() function in a separate JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite

In an exercise for school, there is a website with multiple .js files

The objective of this particular exercise is to get the value of an input field, which is a last name, and compare it to a pre-defined database for autocompletion.

I have to modify file1.js, where I have created a variable that selects the correct input field... I know how to access the string.

Once I have the string, I have to compare it to a known database for any possible Last-name matches... the function is already defined in another file (file2.js), and it looks somewhat like this

```
server.get("/find_relative/:lastName", (req, res) => {
  let lastName = zahteva.params.lastName;
  findCustomerByLastName(lastName, (error, customer) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.send(customer);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not quite sure how to use this function in file1.js, because it's not defined as a variable of any kind... Can anyone help me understand?

Thank you

Comment: It depends where you are running the code. If you have an html file where all the javascript files are referenced in <script> tag, then you can access any fuction in any file just make sure the declarations and <script> tags are in order

Comment: How would I use it in this case, as I can't see it having an assigned name (like a variable) - how do I reference this?

Comment: it seems as if server is an Global variable so it should be also available in file1. can you try console.log(server) and see if result is not undefined.

Comment: in case server is available. You can directly query the server and get lastname as shown in the above code.

Comment: I had the wrong idea about what this even was... turns out this part defines the server's response to a HTTP request, so I have to send a HTTP request from the client (I think the file I'm working on is client-side), and compare the response...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code in `file2.js` is some kind of Node.js server code. I think you're expected to make a GET request like this (lastName is defined as the URL parameter): `localhost:8888/find_relative?lastName=Smith`.

For making GET/POST/other requests one standard way is to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).